# Retrieve firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the firebase data tree
[image]

There are two parents and each having two child each. How to retrieve all the data for "sex".

Here's is my code.

```
ref.child("Doctor").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for child in result {

                    print("Here 1")
                    print(child)
                    let gender = child.value!["sex"] as? String
                    print("Here 2")
                    //print("Sex")
                    print(gender)
                }

            } else {
                print("no results")
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

When I am printing the value of gender, it is showing **nil** value.

Comment: could you please add what you are getting from `print(child)`?

Comment: I'm getting nil value.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why are you getting your child snapshots `nil` here. The problem that I can see in your code is that you are only iterating in the parent nodes. You will need to iterate one more level deep to get the child nodes that have the sex information. But keep in mind that your data structure is not reliable and clean at all, i strongly recommend you to get some time to refactor it. I don't know why do you have this 2 level deep childs with keys but you should be separating them in two different branches in the database.

Comment: Answer below. For a next question, please include the JSON as text instead of a picture, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to skip a level in your code. You listen to the value of the root node and then loop over its children. This gets you snapshots of the nodes `Msm...` and `eqn...`. If you check inside those nodes, neither of them has a child property `sex`.

To solve this, add one more loop in your code to get into the push IDs (the keys starting with `-K`):

```
ref.child("Doctor").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for child in result {
                for child2 in child.children {
                    let gender = child2.value!["sex"] as? String
                    print(gender)
                }
            }

        } else {
            print("no results")
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: I am getting error in the following line
result2 = result.childred.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]

Error is "Value of type [FIRDataSnapshop] has no member 'children'"